# JavaFx: Button border and hover

Tags: java, css, javafx, java-8

I am using Java 8. I have toolbar and buttons on it.

I want to implement the following:

- In usual state (without mouse hover) at toolbar, only button label must be seen (no background, nor borders).
- When the user mouse hovers over the button, then the usual button must be seen.

How to do it via css?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the styles to remove the background :

```
.button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

On hover, to bring back everything just use the button style from `modena.css` :

```
.button:hover{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3px, 3px, 2px, 1px;
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.666667em 0.333333em 0.666667em; /* 4 8 4 8 */
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-content-display: LEFT;
}
```

Comment: FYI guys, the numbers might be off, for example in fx-background-insets i used 0, 1, 2 and for fx-backgroundradius: i used 5, 4, 3 Worked like a charm. I know this is a really really old question.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with netzwerg. If you are using fxml with javafx then you should include these lines of codes in initialize() method of your controller class.

Example of controller class:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{
    private Button test;
    private static final String IDLE_BUTTON_STYLE = "-fx-background-color: transparent;";
    private static final String HOVERED_BUTTON_STYLE = "-fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;";

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        button.setStyle(IDLE_BUTTON_STYLE);
        button.setOnMouseEntered(e -> button.setStyle(HOVERED_BUTTON_STYLE));
        button.setOnMouseExited(e -> button.setStyle(IDLE_BUTTON_STYLE));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Background transparency can be controlled through mouse listeners, i.e. by setting the CSS programmatically (which alleviates the need for an external stylesheet):

```
final String IDLE_BUTTON_STYLE = "-fx-background-color: transparent;";
final String HOVERED_BUTTON_STYLE = "-fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;";


button.setStyle(IDLE_BUTTON_STYLE);
button.setOnMouseEntered(e -> button.setStyle(HOVERED_BUTTON_STYLE));
button.setOnMouseExited(e -> button.setStyle(IDLE_BUTTON_STYLE));
```